# Google Spreadsheet add same cell value

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

I want to add a cell value with its previous value (of the same cell) but it says that there's a circular dependency. How to solve it? (I.E.: B2 cell value = 4, now I enter in the same cell and type 5, then add 5 to 4 (previous value) then show it = 9).

Comment: A cell's formula cannot refer to itself so `B2` cannot be in the formula of cell `B2`

Comment: so how can I perform this kind of operation?

Comment: You will need to do the calculation in a different cell or write a GoogleScript to automate the process for you

Comment: ok, in a different cell. But how? please write a real example.

Comment: You'll just need to store the two values in separate cells and then total them in a third cell e.g. `B2 = 4`, `C2 = 5` and `D2 = SUM(B2:C2)`

Comment: There is a way to do this without adding a new column.  See answer.  You will need to use Apps Script and add an "On Edit" trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to manually "install" a trigger and use the following code:

```
function editSameCell(e) {
  var editedCell,calculatedValue,enteredValue,oldCellValue;

  //Currently the last part of this code runs for every cell edited
  //You should check the column and/or the row to only run the remaining
  //lines of code if the cell being edited is the cell that you want
  //changed

  oldCellValue = e.oldValue;

  Logger.log('oldCellValue: ' + oldCellValue);
  Logger.log('isNaN(oldCellValue): ' + isNaN(oldCellValue));

  if (isNaN(oldCellValue) || !oldCellValue) {
    return; //Quit here because if the user is entering text there should not
    //be a calculation done
  }

  editedCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getCell(1,1);

  enteredValue = editedCell.getValue();
  Logger.log('enteredValue: ' + enteredValue);
  Logger.log('typeof enteredValue: ' + typeof enteredValue);

  if (!enteredValue) {//If for example the cell value was deleted do not enter a new value
    return;  
  };

  calculatedValue = Number(oldCellValue) + Number(enteredValue);
  editedCell.setValue(calculatedValue);

}
```

To install an "On Edit" trigger, click on the "Resources" menu in the code editor, and then choose "Current project's triggers".   Add a trigger if none are already added.  Find the name of the function in the drop down list etc.