# Google Sheets sum of oldvalue and new value of the same cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I was referred to this website by a product expert in Google Docs Community Help center. I am trying to get the sum of the old value and the new value from the same cell. I'm dealing with numbers that constantly changes but I'd like to sum them all up instead of overwriting the cell data with the new data but only for data under column K. Here is a copy of the sheet I'm working on: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pArYf_651_6u1xpKUll94JIJ72V5ALdlOJ2bGQB6P_w/edit?resourcekey=0-uPU0RkaH5ntqYzKQMplXyw#gid=0

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LC3L.png)
In this screenshot, what I need is the Duration column to always refer its old value so that when it changes it will just sum the oldvalue + newvalue.

I've researched this site and found this [Google Spreadsheet add same cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621360/google-spreadsheet-add-same-cell-value). It appears relevant to my case but I can't quite add the onEdit trigger manually. Can anyone help installing the trigger? Also, can the function trigger for column K only?

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: If a cell is edited by a user the the onEdit trigger collects the old Value and the new Value but if those changes occur as a result of another script or formula changing them then that data is not recorded.